# Rock paper scissor game with python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to separate the GUI and the game logic using object oriented but when Im trying to display the "self.result" using tkinter.Label its show "PY VAR1".
Can anyone please help how to update the self.result?

rockpaperscissor.py

```
import random


class RockPaperScissor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rock = 'rock'
        self.paper = 'paper'
        self.scissor = 'scissor'
        self.playerA_win = 'player A win'
        self.playerB_win = 'player B win'
        self.draw = 'Its draw'
        self.playerA_score = 0
        self.playerB_score = 0
        self.choices = {'rock': self.rock,
                    'paper': self.paper,
                    'scissor': self.scissor}
    self.transition = {
                  (self.rock, self.rock): self.draw,
                  (self.rock, self.paper): self.playerB_win,
                  (self.rock, self.scissor): self.playerA_win,
                  (self.paper, self.rock): self.playerA_win,
                  (self.paper, self.paper): self.draw,
                  (self.paper, self.scissor): self.playerB_win,
                  (self.scissor, self.rock): self.playerB_win,
                  (self.scissor, self.paper): self.playerA_win,
                  (self.scissor, self.scissor): self.draw}

    def play(self, playerA, playerB):
        self.playerA_answer = self.choices[playerA]
        self.playerB_answer = self.choices[playerB]
        self.result = self.transition[self.playerA_answer,
                                  self.playerB_answer]

    def get_result(self):
        return self.result

def computer():
    choices = ('rock', 'paper', 'scissor')
    playerB = random.choice(choices)
    return playerB


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rps = RockPaperScissor()
    while True:
        playerA = input('What is your guess? ')
        playerB = computer()
        rps.play(playerA,playerB)
        print(rps.get_result())
```

and

rockpaperscissor_gui.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import rockpaperscissor as rps


class MyFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.value = tk.StringVar()
        self.result = tk.StringVar()
        self.choice = ('rock', 'paper', 'scissor')
        self.rps = rps.RockPaperScissor()
        for i in self.choice:
            self.radio = tk.Radiobutton(self,
                                        text=i,
                                        variable=self.value,
                                        value=i).pack()
        self.button = tk.Button(self,
                                text='play',
                                command=self.play).pack()
        self.label = tk.Label(self,
                              text=self.result).pack()

    def play(self):
        playerA = self.value.get()
        playerB = rps.computer()
        self.rps.play(playerA, playerB)
        self.result.set('result: {0}'.format(self.result))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyFrame().mainloop()
```

this is the screenshot [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl1fS.png)

Comment: There's no question here.

Comment: i want to update the Label but its show "PY VAR1"

Comment: You might want to read this and adjust your question accordingly http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Im trying to display the "self.result" using tkinter.Label but i dont know how,  its show "PY VAR1"

Comment: I think you use wrong variable. `self.result` is `tk.StringVar()` - you have to display `self.rps.get_result()`

Comment: and use `textvariable=self.result` in `Label`

Comment: btw: `pack()` returns `None` so `self.button`, `self.label` and `self.radio` is `None`. First assign widget to variables then use `variable.pack()` (if you need this variable) . You don't have to assign widget to variable if you don't use this variable.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answer now its working!
this is the new code

```
#rockpaperscissor_gui.py
import tkinter as tk
import random as rn
import rockpaperscissor as rps


class RockPaperScissor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rps = rps.RockPaperScissor()
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.playerA = tk.StringVar()
        self.playerA.set('Pick your answer')
        self.playerB = tk.StringVar()
        self.playerB.set('Pick your answer')
        self.result = tk.StringVar()
        self.rps.playerA_score = tk.StringVar()
        self.rps.playerB_score = tk.StringVar()
        self.choices = ('rock', 'paper', 'scissor')
        self.label_choices = (self.playerA, self.playerB, self.result)

        for item in self.label_choices:
            self.label = tk.Label(self.root, textvariable=item)
            self.label.pack()
        for item in self.choices:
            self.radiobutton = tk.Radiobutton(self.root, text=item,
                                              variable=self.playerA,
                                              value=item)
            self.radiobutton.pack()

        self.button = tk.Button(self.root,
                                text='update',
                                command=self.update).pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def update(self):
        self.playerB_answer = rn.choice(self.choices)
        self.playerB.set(self.playerB_answer)
        player = self.playerA.get()
        computer = self.playerB.get()
        self.rps.play(player, computer)
        answer = self.rps.get_result()
        self.result.set(answer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    RockPaperScissor()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `textvariable` in `Label` and display `self.rps.get_result()`

btw: you don't have to assign widget to variable if you don't use this variable.

Code could be like this

```
import tkinter as tk
import rockpaperscissor as rps


class MyFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.value = tk.StringVar()
        self.result = tk.StringVar()
        self.choice = ('rock', 'paper', 'scissor')
        self.rps = rps.RockPaperScissor()
        for i in self.choice:
            tk.Radiobutton(self,
                            text=i,
                            variable=self.value,
                            value=i).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='play', command=self.play).pack()
        tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.result).pack() # textvariable

    def play(self):
        playerA = self.value.get()
        playerB = rps.computer()
        self.rps.play(playerA, playerB)
        self.result.set('result: {0}'.format(self.rps.get_result())) # get_result()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyFrame().mainloop()
```